# sneakyinput not reading button when joystick is held down

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem with SneakyJoystick and SneakyButton. SneakyButton is not being read as pressed when the joystick is held down and I was wondering how to get around that. I assume multitouch allows that both input be read simultaneously. In my current project, whenever the joystick is held down the character moves in that direction, but i can't seem to press a sneakyinput button while the joystick is held down.

heres my update method for the InputLayer:

```
GameLayer *game = [GameLayer sharedGameLayer];
Hero* hero =[game getHeroFromLayer];
if (attackButton.active)
{
    [hero attack];
}


CGPoint velocity = ccpMult(dPad.velocity, 6500 * dt);
hero.position = ccp(hero.position.x + velocity.x * dt,
                    hero.position.y + velocity.y * dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sup dude? You should try changing

`if (attackButton.active)`

to

`if (attackButton.value == 1)`

Comment: I just gave that a shot and i'm still having the same problem = (. thanks though

Comment: ahh nevermind, i figured it out. LOL silly me. i just had to enable multitouch. duh!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Gnoob.

After many days struggling with how to concurrently touch on both joystick and attack/jump button but totally failed. Until now I touch this comment, just turn multitouch on, everything works!!!

Change Here:
RootViewController.mm => [eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]